# Inserting data from dataframe into numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am inserting data from a dataframe `df` with 55 rows into a numpy array `matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues` with a shape of (55,60). I am doing this using the code below. However, I get the error `IndexError: index 55 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 55`. `months_to_maturity` contains the numbers `[6:6:330]`.

```
for (i,row) in df.iterrows():
    matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues[i,0:(row.months_to_maturity/ 6)-1] = 1/2
    matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues[i,(row.months_to_maturity/6)-1] = 3/2
```

Thank You

Comment: Can you verify that `df` does indeed have 55 rows?  From the looks of the code, it seems like `i` is getting a value of 55, which could only occur if `df`  had more than 55 rows.  Perhaps you could try something like `print(len(list(df.iterrows())))` to see if it is indeed 55.

Comment: can you please show how your dataframe looks like? Especially the index.

Comment: @brenns10 `print(len(list(df.iterrows())))` results in 55.

Comment: Interesting. It occurs to me that if you've deleted any rows from the dataframe, than the index won't go from 0 to 54 like you might expect, it'll have gaps.  It would be helpful if you checked, as @AnandSKumar suggested, what the index contains.

Comment: I just realized that I need to reset the index for the dataframe. Its sorted now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For any future visitors, here's what happened:

A DataFrame's index serves to label each row uniquely, so when you delete a row, that index is removed and you have a "gap" in the index.  This is very good when you have a meaningful index.  But, when you just want the index to number your rows, it's not what you want.  In this case, `df` contained 55 rows, but the index had holes, so the largest index was something larger than 55, causing an IndexError in the matrix.  As an example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], columns=['x','y'])

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   x  y
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6

In [4]: df = df.drop(1)

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
   x  y
0  1  2
2  5  6
```

In order to remedy this situation, you can simply reassign the index to be a list containing the correct range of numbers:

```
In [6]: df.index = list(range(len(df.index)))

In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
   x  y
0  1  2
1  5  6
```

Answer (score 0):

or you could use pandas [reset_index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```
In [18]: df.drop(1).reset_index()
Out[18]:
   index  x  y
0      0  1  2
1      2  5  6
```